# How to order products by title/ Name angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have this application, where the products are displayed using ng repeat. The client wants a particular product to always come first in the order based on its title, example :

From a list of products, the client wants the product with title "SUPER MAC" to always be on top or displayed as the first item in the list of product items.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Ryan

Answer (score 0):

**Simply create two arrays and iterate first through the top items and then through the rest.**

```
$scope.topItems = ['Super Mac'];
$scope.items = ['foo', 'bar'];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you can do:

You can use the `sort` function of the `Array` to implement your sorting by title like:

```
var arr = [ {title: 'Food', age: 50}, {tile: 'Supermarket', age: 50}, {title: 'zebra', age: 50}, ];
arr.sort(function(a,b){ return (a.title === "zebra" || b.title === "zebra") ? 1 : 0; } );
```

You can read more about it here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

> **Important**: The above sample is only a guidance most likely you will need to define the sorting that best meet your needs.

Then you could implement this function in a custom filter:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.filter('myFilter', function() {
        return function(items,param1) {                                     
              items.sort(function(a,b){ return (a.title === param1 || b.title === param1) ? 1 : 0; } );

        });
        }
    });
```

This would work in your HTML like:

```
<ul ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <li ng-repeat="row in someItems |myFilter:'zebra' ">{{row.title}}</li>
<ul>
```

By taking advantage of the angular filter you could pass the item you want at the top from the view which from my POV meets better the MVVM pattern because it avoids  adding additional code to either your controller or services with things that may only make sense or be necessary in a particular view.